# Llama 2 model is not giving accurate responses on numerical data

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama, pinecone

I've created a Document Question Answering Bot using TheBloke/Llama-2-chat-7b-GPTQ and langchain. My model is working best on text data but when it comes to numerical form of data it is not giving accurate responses. I've pdfs that contain rates of the services. and when i ask the question about the rates it first give me correct answer when only that single document is upserted on Pinecone database. But when I upsert multiple pdfs it does not give me accurate response.

I've used different embeddings, changed different methods of doing but still doesn't get any appropriate solution. Here is my code.

```
model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-GPTQ"
model_basename = "model"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, use_fast=True)
model = AutoGPTQForCausalLM.from_quantized(
    model_name_or_path,
    revision="gptq-4bit-32g-actorder_True",
    model_basename = model_basename,
    use_safetensors= True,
    trust_remote_code= True,
    inject_fused_attention=False,
    quantize_config=None,
    device= DEVICE,)
generation_config = GenerationConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path)
pipe = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer= tokenizer,
    #max_length=4000,
    max_new_tokens = 1000,
    temperature=0,
    top_p= 0.95,
    repetition_penalty= 1.15,
    generation_config=generation_config,
    streamer = streamer,
    batch_size = 1,
)
llm= HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)
embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(
    model_name = "hkunlp/instructor-xl", model_kwargs={"device":DEVICE}
)
`text_field = "text"
db = Pinecone(index, embeddings.embed_query, text_field)

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = """
### Instruction: You're an Virtual Assistant. Use only the chat history and the following information
{context} to answer the question. If you don't know the answer - say that you don't know.
Always reply to greetings in short and concise manner.
Keep your replies short, compassionate, and informative.
{chat_history}
### Input: {question}
### Response:
"""
class Chatbot:
  def __init__(
      self,
      text_pipeline: HuggingFacePipeline,
      embeddings:HuggingFaceEmbeddings,
      prompt_template: str = DEFAULT_TEMPLATE,
      verbose: bool = False,
  ):
    prompt = PromptTemplate (
        input_variables = ["context", "question", "chat_history"],
        template = prompt_template,
    )
    self.chain = self._create_chain(text_pipeline, prompt, verbose)
    self.db = Pinecone(index, embeddings.embed_query, "text")
    self.retriever = db.as_retriever(search_type="mmr")

  def _create_chain(self,text_pipeline: HuggingFacePipeline,prompt: PromptTemplate,verbose: bool = False,):
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        memory_key = "chat_history",
        human_prefix = "### Input",
        ai_prefix = "### Response",
        input_key = "question",
        output_key = "output_text",
        return_messages = False,
    )
    return load_qa_chain(
        text_pipeline,
        chain_type="stuff",
        prompt=prompt,
        memory=memory,
        verbose=False,

    )
  def __call__(self,user_input:str)->str:
    docs = self.retriever.get_relevant_documents(user_input)
    return self.chain.run({"input_documents":docs, "question": user_input})
```

Comment: The same issue happened to me. For me it gets year wrong. For example, ir convert 2022 to 202 or 2023, 2004 to 204.

Comment: I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time. Here's something you need to ensure: different embedding models will yield different results. When a chunk is retrieved from the vector database contains missing information, and sent to the Llama model, it will fill in the missing information based on its own observations and learning even though you try to prompt engineer it, Llama lacks on prompt engineer according to their research paper. An alternative to creating an accurate RAG-based project is to implement OpenAI's models (GPT-3.5, 4). It will work accurately.

Comment: I don't have Internet access on my deployment machine. I have 24GB RTX GPU. Would there be any other Open Source model that can fit and precise with fact and figures? I use it for summarization of documents that has fact & figures, and dates.

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad A quantized Mixtral8x8b?

Comment: Can you give me a link to it? Can It be fit ot 24GB GPU memory?

Comment: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Mixtral-8x7B-v0.1-GGUF/tree/main Q4_0 should fit...